# Command works in terminal, but not in script

Tags: command-line, scripts

I have looked through all similar issues and can't find a solution.

I am running Ubuntu Desktop 16.04.
I need this command to execute in the background and continue to run.

```
/usr/bin/avconv -f alsa -i loopout -f mp3 - 2>/dev/null | sudo /usr/bin/ezstream -qvc /etc/ezstream.xml
```

It gives me the expected results if I run it in a terminal or if I put it in an sh script and run that script in terminal.  But I have tried creating a startup object in the GUI to run the script and I have also tried to run the script in cron.

(`crontab -e` as user)

```
@reboot /home/administrator/stream.sh
```

I have also tried running it in `rc.local`.  Nothing works.

The odd thing is, I have it running exactly the same way in osmc (Debian) and it works flawlessly.

Comment: Does the script have execute permissions?
ls -l /home/administrator/stream.sh

Comment: It does.  As I mentioned, if I run the script in terminal, it works as expected.

Comment: When you try to run a `sudo` command from within cron, there's no tty for it to authenticate through. If you need to gain root permission in a cron job, place it in root's crontab (`sudo crontab -e`) or the system-wide crontab `/etc/crontab`

Comment: Yes, I apologize.  I removed that sudo command and no change.  And oddly, it still runs as a direct terminal command without the sudo.  I didn't think there was crontab for root.

Comment: instead of redirecting the STDERR of avconv to /dev/null, redirect it to a readable file and increase verbosity with -loglevel debug, and ezstream with -v

Comment: How would you ssh to "radio"?

Comment: No, I can not connect by `ssh radio` or by `ssh radio@ianprices.com`.

Answer (score 0):

My guess `avconv` needs pseudo-terminal.
And you don't have it if started from cron.

Try to set env var `AV_LOG_FORCE_NOCOLOR=1`. (taken from avconv man page)

Answer (score 0):

Try the next:

- Modify your script

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  echo "My script execution" | logger
  /usr/bin/avconv -f alsa -i loopout -f mp3 - 2>/dev/null | /usr/bin/ezstream -qvc /etc/ezstream.xml | logger
  echo "End of my script execution" | logger
  ```
- Modify your crontab: `sudo crontab -e` the next way to get results faster:

  ```
  * * * * * /home/administrator/stream.sh
  ```

  or

  ```
  * * * * * /bin/bash -c "/home/administrator/stream.sh"
  ```
- Run `journalctl -f` in another terminal's window to see what happens

Try also to run your script as root, using root's crontab:

```
sudo crontab -e
```